# Strange output from kafka key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am experimenting with Kafka Streams and wrote a simple first application.

I have created a topic and in my code I call:

```
final KStream<String, Upload> uploadStream = builder.stream(UPLOADS_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), uploadSerde));
```

The upload serdes is created using a .avsc file, initialised as:

```
final SpecificAvroSerde<Upload> uploadSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
uploadSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
```

I have output the contents using:

```
uploadStream.foreach((k, v) -> System.out.println("uploadStream: Key: " + k + ", Value: " + v));
```

My issues is that the output seems to have a couple of characters in front of the key value and I am not sure if this is ok or not:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFre0.jpg

I have a simple driver program, that uses the same avro schema.

Are those strange characters just standard control characters or is there a problem with my deserialization?

Comment: What serializer is used for the key when writing to the input topic?

Comment: Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
    Schema schema = parser.parse(userSchema);
 GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
 ProducerRecord<Object, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<>("topic_name", key, avroRecord);
 
 I use the standard avroRecord.put(<field_name>, <value>);

Comment: Your comment does not explain what key serializer you use... The producer should be configures with a key and value serializer. What do you set in the producer config? Also `ProducerRecord` is typed with `<Object, Object>` and what type is `key` ?

Comment: In  that case I am not using one. The key is a Java String type that is passed straight into the ProducerRecord. I use Serdes.String() on the consumer. Is that my issue? What key serializer should I use?

Comment: Sorry, I see this in my producer: props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
              io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Producer does use a different key serializer (`KafkaAvroSerializer.class`) on write than your consumer (ie, `KafkaStreams`) on read (`StringSerde`) -- to make it work properly, both need to use the same serializer/deserializer/serde class.

Thus, you either change the producer to use `StringSerializer` instead of `KafkaAvroSerilalizer` or you change your Kafka Streams application to use `SpecificAvroSerde` or `GenericAvroSerde` for the key to read.

Comment: You can't read back as GenericAvroSerde I believe as the GenericRecord type always should be "type"="record" for avro . What else can I use to read a long. In case of long the schema is just  ```{type="long"}```

Comment: AFAIK, primitive types are supported: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/10788d40f1240887e80b65b51952e9f4ad51a281/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.java#L49-L60